# Horizontal navbar menu submenu alignment

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I am creating a navigation bar. When you hover on an item in the navbar, it displays a drop down menu. Certain items on the drop down menu display a submenu when hovered. All this is working, but when the submenu displays, I am having issues with the positioning of its top property. I have tried making its' parent div `position:relative`, adjusting it's top: position, adjusting the display property, etc., but can't seem to locate the problem.

```css
#nav {
  width: 886px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #B1B6B9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #646E73;
  background-color: #A9AFB2;
  /* 50% gray */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #bbbfc1), color-stop(100%, #7f878b));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#ffBBBFC1', EndColorStr='#ff7F878B');
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.navone {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 32px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  z-index: 150;
  width: auto;
}

.navone a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Jabas, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 5px 14px 11px 14px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #B1B6B9;
  border-right: 1px solid #737C81;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(84, 95, 101, .35);
}

.navone a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #567697;
  /* 75% dark blue */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #567697), color-stop(100%, #1e4975));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#ff567697', EndColorStr='#ff1E4975');
}

.navone a.active {
  background-color: #89A8C7;
  /* 55% blue */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #89a8c7), color-stop(100%, #5480ad));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#ff89A8C7', EndColorStr='#ff5480AD');
}

.navone:hover .navtwo {
  display: block;
}

.navtwo {
  border-top: 1px solid #65809B;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(84, 95, 101, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(84, 95, 101, .3);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(84, 95, 101, .3);
}

.navtwo a {
  color: #3E6082;
  background-color: #D8E2EC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 5%;
  border: 1px solid #B1C5DA;
  box-sizing: box-border;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.navtwo a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3E6082;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown > a {
  background: #C1C5C7 !important;
  color: #32393D !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E2E3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A8AB !important;
  z-index: 50;
}

.dropdown > a:after {
  float: right;
  content: "\25B6"
}

.dropdown:hover > a {
  background: #92999D !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  width: 150px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <!--begin of option-->
  <div class="navone">
    <a href="">Option</a>
    <div class="navtwo">
      <!--begin of dropdown menu-->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Test 1</a>
        <!--begin of submenu-->
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Test Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Long Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Longest Submenu</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--begin of dropdown menu-->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Test 2</a>
        <!--begin of submenu-->
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Test</a>
          <a href="#">Long Test</a>
          <a href="#">The Longest Test</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="">Test 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end of option-->


  <div class="navone">
    <a href="#">Longer Option Name</a>
    <div class="navtwo">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Test 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Test Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Long Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Longest Submenu</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="">Test 2</a>
      <a href="">Test 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

*or* **JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/1fsk6fm2/5/

```
 WANTED                                     MINE
 -----------                               -----------
| NavOption |                             | NavOption |
 -----------                               ----------- ---------
| Dropdown  |                             | Dropdown  | Submenu |
 ----------- ----------                    ----------- ---------
| Dropdown >| Submenu  |                  | Dropdown >|           < The submenu is shifting
 ----------- ----------                    -----------              to the top
```

Where the > shows the drop down item that contains sub menu options.

Comment: The snippet and the JSFiddle seems to be ok. Can you share more about the problem?

Comment: I added more, I hope it makes sense.. Right now mine is shifting the sub menu items to the top of the drop down list, instead of aligning the two together. In my code example, it happens under Option > Test 2

Comment: I got it right now and submitted an answer on that. You were not positioning your dropdown containers the right way.

Comment: @InacioSchweller also has to do with the way they are displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a small change on the `.dropdown` selector and now it's working:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c71f6qzm/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thats great, thanks. I'm not too familiar with the clear property. I just looked it up but still uncertain, could you quick explain why that made it work in this situation?

Comment: Sure. The clear property helps to decide if an element next to a floated (float: right or float: left) element must be moved down or can stand by his side.

Comment: In this case, clear is just helping you to prevent your layout to break just in case you put any item in between and is not floated properly

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with your `display` property of your `.dropdown`s.
if you set the display property to `inline-block` on those `<div>`s they should render more correctly. You may have to add `width: 100%` to your `.dropdown` CSS and reduce the white space in between each menu item by adding `font-size: 0` to `.navtwo` css, but it works:

> Also, [Ignacio's float solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35611065/3186555), does pretty much the same thing.
>
> Display: block for those `<div>`s is the problem. floating or displaying as inline is your best solution

```css
#nav {
  width: 886px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #B1B6B9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #646E73;
  background-color: #A9AFB2;
  /* 50% gray */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #bbbfc1), color-stop(100%, #7f878b));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bbbfc1 0%, #7f878b 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#ffBBBFC1', EndColorStr='#ff7F878B');
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.navone {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 32px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  z-index: 150;
  width: auto;
}

.navone a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Jabas, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 5px 14px 11px 14px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #B1B6B9;
  border-right: 1px solid #737C81;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(84, 95, 101, .35);
}

.navone a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #567697;
  /* 75% dark blue */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #567697), color-stop(100%, #1e4975));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #567697 0%, #1e4975 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#ff567697', EndColorStr='#ff1E4975');
}

.navone a.active {
  background-color: #89A8C7;
  /* 55% blue */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #89a8c7), color-stop(100%, #5480ad));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #89a8c7 0%, #5480ad 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#ff89A8C7', EndColorStr='#ff5480AD');
}

.navone:hover .navtwo {
  display: block;
}

.navtwo {
  border-top: 1px solid #65809B;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(84, 95, 101, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(84, 95, 101, .3);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(84, 95, 101, .3);
}

.navtwo a {
  color: #3E6082;
  background-color: #D8E2EC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 5%;
  border: 1px solid #B1C5DA;
  box-sizing: box-border;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.navtwo a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3E6082;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.dropdown > a {
  background: #C1C5C7 !important;
  color: #32393D !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E2E3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A2A8AB !important;
  z-index: 50;
}

.dropdown > a:after {
  float: right;
  content: "\25B6"
}

.dropdown:hover > a {
  background: #92999D !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  width: 150px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <!--begin of option-->
  <div class="navone">
    <a href="">Option</a>
    <div class="navtwo">
      <!--begin of dropdown menu-->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Test 1</a>
        <!--begin of submenu-->
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Test Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Long Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Longest Submenu</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--begin of dropdown menu-->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Test 2</a>
        <!--begin of submenu-->
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Test</a>
          <a href="#">Long Test</a>
          <a href="#">The Longest Test</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="">Test 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end of option-->


  <div class="navone">
    <a href="#">Longer Option Name</a>
    <div class="navtwo">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Test 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Test Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Long Submenu</a>
          <a href="#">Test Longest Submenu</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="">Test 2</a>
      <a href="">Test 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

*or* [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1fsk6fm2/7/)